# How to make onClick to trigger a download a video/photo given a download url?

Tags: reactjs

If I have an array of data
for example

```
["download_url": "example.com/url/23131" ...]
```

and in the return function of the react rendering, how can you make onClick of a button to make user trigger the download of the download_url ?
Thanks

Comment: just opening the URL should trigger the download of links, why not just loop and use `window.open('url', '_blank')`, example: `window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it. Pass your url into that function

```js
export const downloadFile = url => window.location.assign(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: this automatically downloads without clicking

Comment: of course you need to call the function onClick `onClick={() => downloadFile(url)}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your object:

```
let obj =  { "download_url": "example.com/url/23131",
.... };
```

This [ideally](https://css-tricks.com/building-good-download-button/) should be an anchor tag.

```
<a download href={obj["download_url"]}>Download</a>
```

This is more semantically correct than using a button to trigger a download. `anchor` tags are for **resources** and you are redirecting the user to a new resource.

The provision of `download` attribute is a good indication as to how HTML [wants](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#downloading-resources) us to implement it.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that I have to add the onClick function to a Icon material ui component